# Mesh imported from DazStudio always render as pure black

Tags: mesh, materials, hair

I´ve imported a Dforce hair from DazStudio as a *OBJ and although it seems all is fine (other meshes work fine) the Hair mesh (multiple strands) always render black (Cycles and EEVEE)with any material i apply to it.

It doesn't matter what type of material i apply to it, simple or complex, it always render as pure black...

I´m kinda new to Blender as I'm in the first steps of learning it so, any light on the matter would be greatly appreciated!

[Link to the sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/111C1CWTZH5VXsGHSWpbPsMA31QkS9ZGt/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

This hair is not a *"hair"* made with Blender: Blender does not recognize it as hair. This is simply edges and edges cannot be shaded without faces.

Enter edit mode, select all <kbd>A</kbd> and give a very little extrusion <kbd>E</kbd> to the mesh (less than a millimeter or around that).

In the shader part, change the *"hair BSDF"* by a *"Principled"* shader.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I tried that but with the Solidify Modifier... I really thought the solidify Modifier did the same thing as Extrude. Apparently i was mistaken :)

Didn't know the Princpled Hair Shader Node was exclusively to use with Blender Hair Particle System too... That´s why I'm still a noob at Blender currently :)

Anyway, thanks a ton for the answer!

Take care!